# Python, struct.pack_into: How to change the padding bytes from 00 to FF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I'm writing a Python 3.3.2 script. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
...
text = filename.readlines()
self.metadata = bytearray(256)
...
struct.pack_into('32s', self.metadata, 4, text[0])
...
```

Exactly 32 byte are reserved for the content of text[0]. However, the string is shorter than 32 bytes, so the unused bytes are padded with null bytes (0x00), see also [notes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters). I want to change the padding to 0xFF. Is there a nice way to do this other than getting the real size of my string, pack this into my bytearray and then pack the remaining bytes as 0xFF into the bytearray?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the ljust method to first pad the string to 32 bytes with the desired 0xff character? ljust(width[, fillchar]) where width is the total string length after padding, and fillchar is the character to pad with (a space by default.)

```
struct.pack_into('32s', self.metadata, 4, text[0].ljust(32, b'\xff'))
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you! However, there is a problem: I open the file in binary mode to work around some encoding issues (so text[i] is a bytearray), and I want to strip the characters \r and \n from the string. So my complete line is as follows: `struct.pack_into('32s', self.metadata, 4, bytes(str(text[0], 'utf-8').strip('\r\n'), encoding='utf-8'))`. Adding the ljust call results in the error `struct.pack_into('32s', self.metadata, 4, bytes(str(text[0], 'utf-8').strip('\r\n').ljust(32, b'\xff'), encoding='utf-8'))
TypeError: The fill character cannot be converted to Unicode`

Comment: yes, naturally if you're encoding to utf-8 you have to add the padding character after the encoding step, otherwise you will encode '\xff' to utf-8 too (which seems like an invalid character in unicode?) so the ljust method won't help you here.

Answer (score 1):

First initialize the bytearray with 0xFF

```
metadata = bytearray(b'\xFF'*256)
```